# How to move a window if titlebar is overlapped by Ubuntu menu

Tags: window

Somehow the title-bar of chrome was overlapped by Ubuntu menu-bar like attached image.

In this case how to move this chrome window?

[image: window overlapped by titlebar]

Comment: all the proposed answers using Alt key work, but are temporarily! is there a permanent solution? i have some windows that open for some reason in this position. it seems Ubuntu isn't remembering the new position.

Comment: See this question for one solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/368446/have-terminal-window-file-explorer-remember-their-last-size-and-position

Answer (score 5, accepted):

press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> Then move the mouse, the window will move with it.

Comment: Good! I'm still playing with it.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Hold down the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and left click and drag the window to a new position. You should be able to move the window to another location.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch the position of the Ubuntu Panel to the left, right, or bottom of the screen temporarily until you can move the window to a safe position, then move the panel back to it's default area (or area or preference)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to spread the workspaces using <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> or the workspace icon in the launcher (if enabled), then just drag the window away from the panel.