# Have terminal window & file explorer remember their last size and position

Tags: 13.10, gnome-terminal, window-manager

In Ubuntu 13.10 I would like my terminal window to, by default, open with the same size and in the same position as last time. I would like similar behaviour for the file explorer.

Is this possible?

To clarify: I am *not* interested in persisting this across a reboot, but only within a session. (I.e. [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8834/how-do-i-save-remember-last-used-window-position-and-size-for-applications) is not relevant.)

Answer (score 4):

This does work for me.

If using Unity on 13.10, you can achieve this with ccsm (CompizComfig Settings Manager).
You have to have it installed (*following command should've already be done*)

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra
```

Launch ccsm.

FOR SIZE:
Activate module **Window Rules** under Window Management category.
Click the button Window Rules, you should see a tab pane with two tabs: Matches and Sizes.
Click on Sizes tab and add any app you want to specify its size with the New button.
Indicate the desired width and height and to which windows(s) you want the width and height to be always the same.

FOR POSITION:
Do the same as above but with module **Place Windows**.

Then try to close then open one of the windows you specified.

*I'd like to include some screenshots but I'm told that I need reputation 10 at least before I can add images to my posts.*

EDIT:
Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nr7N.png (ccsm with above modules buttons on a fresh French install of Ubuntu 13.10 - Ubuntu Saucy installed on 06-dec-2013) -- Even if texts may differ from French to English, icons on the screenshot are the same on every install of ccsm.

Comment: Post the screenshots to some well accessible site and mention the URLs in your answer - somebody will merge them into it.

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful. However I'm using Unity on 13.10, and have CompizConfig Settings Manager installed, but I don't get exactly the buttons/windows/tabs you describe (so screenshots would be useful). Maybe I have a different version of CompizConfig Settings Manager. For example I don't see a module called Window Rules under Window Management.
Also I'm assuming this allows *fixing* size and position, rather than *remembering the last* size and position, which is really what I'm after.