# I'm running Ubuntu 12.4 how do I move a window from the top right corner

Tags: tabs

So I am running Ubuntu 12.4 and sometimes when I click on an Icon it puts the window in the top right/left hand corner and I can't figure out how to move it so I can close out of it or move it or put it in full screen.
How do I fix this?
Thanks :D

Comment: Recommend upgrading.  12.04 is two years old now.

Comment: @blujay: That is no reason for recommending an upgrade.

Comment: this question is already answered here 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/363452/how-to-move-a-window-if-titlebar-is-overlapped-by-ubuntu-menu

Comment: Jobin, Unity isn't mature now, and it was even less mature 2 years ago.  Little irritating bugs like this are the kind that are often fixed in upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and then you will see a context menu which will have the option to move the window. Use the keyboard navigation keys to move the window to wherever you want.

Comment: @user255629: You may consider marking the answer as accepted if it has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ mouse left click hold to move the window if you can click a small part of it. Otherwise you can use the "Put" plugin in compiz settings manager to assign keyboard shortcuts to moving window actions.

Answer (score 0):

press ctrl-alt-num

1-7-9-3 correspond to the four corners.
4-8-6-2 correspond to the left,top,right and bottom half of the screen.
5 corresponds to full screen (do it twice to maximize)
0 corresponds to minimize