# How to move a window if titlebar is overlapped by Ubuntu menu

Tags: unity, 14.04, window-placement

okey i know this is a duplicate of: [How to move a window if titlebar is overlapped by Ubuntu menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363452/how-to-move-a-window-if-titlebar-is-overlapped-by-ubuntu-menu/456862?noredirect=1#comment601092_456862)
but some smuck wouldn't let me comment, so i had to start a new question.

all the proposed answers using <kbd>Alt</kbd> work, but are temporarily! is there a permanent solution? i have some windows that open for some reason in this position. it seems Ubuntu isn't remembering the new position.

Comment: What do you mean 'some smuck wouldn't let you comment'?

Comment: smuck in the best meaning of the word.. btw! i haven got enough points to comment. so my new answer/comment was deleted.
the problem is not really a duplicate but an extension of the question.

Comment: You got the 'comment everywhere priveledge now'. Enjoy.

Comment: If it's not a duplicate but an "extension of the question," don't say you know it's a duplicate in the body....